# Anaconda: ImportError: Cannot import name '_imaging' from 'PIL' (matplotlib.pyplot)

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, importerror

I'm trying to plot the histogram using matplotlib.pyplot library.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.hist(df["xxx"])
```

When I'm trying to import that library I'm getting the error:

> ImportError: cannot import name '*imaging' from 'PIL'(C:\Users\Taras\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\PIL_*init**.py)

I'm using Anaconda and Jupyter Notebook.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code as you have made it very complicated

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
plt.hist(df["xxx"])
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! But I have a problem with importing the matplotlib library, not with the code itself. Do you have any ideas on how to solve ImportError?

Comment: If the issue is not solved yet you can get an idea from here: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/10277/

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the first line of your code to the following:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

The second line of code is okay, but I don't understand what the third line of code is doing.  What dataframe are you trying to print?  I copied and pasted a dataframe from the web and then ran your code changing the first and third lines of code.

All runs good in Jupyter Lab using the python kernel.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import pyplot    

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'name':['john','mary','peter','jeff','bill','lisa','jose'],
    'age':[23,78,22,19,45,33,20],
    'gender':['M','F','M','M','M','F','M'],
    'state':['california','dc','california','dc','california','texas','texas'],
    'num_children':[2,0,0,3,2,1,4],
    'num_pets':[5,1,0,5,2,2,3]
})

df.plot(kind='hist',x='num_children',y='num_pets',color='red')
plt.show()
```

The plot can be viewed at the link below.

[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6KZoH.png)

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! But I have a problem with importing the matplotlib library, not with the code itself. Do you have any ideas on how to solve ImportError?

Comment: Did you replace your first line of code with the suggested code?   One more thing.  I very much do not like Anaconda.  Anaconda creates a huge layer of unknown between the user and the software.  Experienced users tend to not use Anaconda.

Comment: Thanks, man! One more question: what would you recommend to use instead of Anaconda?

Comment: You do it yourself.  Using Anaconda is cheating you from knowing those things people need to know.  You will need to install python yourself.  You will need to use pip for installing and updating python's packages.  Best of all, when you have a question about python or jupyter, then you can find specific answers to your questions.  Otherwise using Anaconda inevitably means nobody knows anything and you should try to reinstall Anaconda.  And that's a really crappy way of trying to understand software, libraries, and dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

you can solve this problem by import Image lib manually

```
import PIL
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Answer (score 0):

Unistalling and reinstalling pillow should work.

```py
pip uninstall Pillow
pip install Pillow
```

Answer (score -1):

Guys listen for me the error was actually with jupyter notebook. I was actually running jupyter notebook on my vs code .
VS code  ---> New terminal ---> type " python -m notebook "
makesure you have installed PIP Jupyter
----->" pip install jupyterlab "
I was getting error when i insert "%matplotlib" with saying error " NOmodule  PIL"

i spend my time behind pip PILLOw
there is no use ... at last i foundout the solution .....

if your a datascience analyser .. then its better to download Anaconda which comes with already inbuild package like Jupyter Notebook ....once u installed it ...uwont be finding any wrror like me ..... hope this solves your issues